# Run two sequential bash scripts in parallel 4 times

Tags: bash, parallel-processing

I have a list of configuration files:

```
cfg1.cfg
cfg2.cfg
cfg3.cfg
cfg4.cfg
cfg5.cfg
cfg6.cfg
cfg7.cfg
...
```

that serve as input for two scripts:

```
script1.sh
script2.sh
```

which I run sequentially as follows:

```
script1.sh cfgX.cfg && script2.sh cfgX.cfg
```

where X=1, 2, 3, ...

These scripts are not parallelised and take a long time to run. How can I launch them in parallel, let's say 4 at the time, so I do not kill the server where I run them?

For just one script I tried a brute force approach similar to:

```
export COUNTER_LIMIT=4

export COUNTER=1

for each in $(ls *.cfg)
do

INSTRUCTION="./script1.sh $each "

if (($COUNTER >= $COUNTER_LIMIT)) ; 
then
$INSTRUCTION   &&
export COUNTER=$(($COUNTER-$COUNTER_LIMIT));
echo
sleep 600s
else
$INSTRUCTION  &
sleep 5s
fi

echo $COUNTER
export COUNTER=$(($COUNTER+1));

done
```

(the sleeps are because for some reason the scripts cannot be initiated at the same time...)

So, ho can I do so that the double ampersands in

```
script1.sh cfgX.cfg && script2.sh cfgX.cfg
```

dont' block the brute force parallelisation?

I also accept better and simpler approaches ;)

Cheers
jorge

**UPDATE**

I should have mentioned that the config files are not necessarily sequentially named and can have any name, I just made them like this to make the example as simple as possible.

Comment: for a given config file, does `script1.sh` need to complete before you can run `script2.sh`?

Comment: yes, that is the main issue, or I could just use one ampersand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
parallel --jobs 4  \
         --load 50% \
         --bar       \
         --eta "( echo 1st-for-{}; echo 2nd-for-{} )" < aListOfAdHocArguments.txt
0% 0:5=0s
1st-for-Abraca
2nd-for-Abraca
20% 1:4=0s                                                                                                                                                                                                 
1st-for-Dabra
2nd-for-Dabra
40% 2:3=0s                                                                                                                                                                                                 
1st-for-Hergot
2nd-for-Hergot
60% 3:2=0s                                                                                                                                                                                                 
1st-for-Fagot
2nd-for-Fagot
80% 4:1=0s                                                                                                                                                                                                 

100% 5:0=0s
```

> **Q** : *How can I launch them in parallel, let's **say 4 at the time**, so I do **not kill the server** where I run them?*

A lovely task for GNU **`parallel`**.

First let's check the localhost ecosystem ( exosystems, executing `parallel`-jobs over `ssh`-connected remote-hosts possible, yet exceed the scope of this post ) :

```
parallel --number-of-cpus
parallel --number-of-cores
parallel --show-limits
```

For more configuration details beyond the **`--jobs 4`**, potentially `--memfree` or `--noswap`, `--load <max-load>` or `--keep-order` and `--results <aFile>` or `--output-as-files` :

```
man parallel
```

---

```
parallel --jobs 4 \
         --bar     \
         --eta "( script1.sh cfg{}.cfg; script2.sh cfg{}.cfg )" ::: {1..123}
```

Here,
 emulated by a just pair of tandem `echo`-s for down-counted indexes, so progress-bars are invisible and **E**stimated-**T**ime-of-**A**rrival `--eta` indications are almost instant... :

```
parallel --jobs 4  \
         --load 50% \
         --bar       \
         --eta "( echo 1st-for-cfg-{}; echo 2nd-for-cfg-{} )" ::: {10..0}
0% 0:11=0s 7                                                                                                                                                                                               
1st-for-cfg-10
2nd-for-cfg-10
9% 1:10=0s 6                                                                                                                                                                                               
1st-for-cfg-9
2nd-for-cfg-9
18% 2:9=0s 5                                                                                                                                                                                               
1st-for-cfg-8
2nd-for-cfg-8
27% 3:8=0s 4                                                                                                                                                                                               
1st-for-cfg-7
2nd-for-cfg-7
36% 4:7=0s 3                                                                                                                                                                                               
1st-for-cfg-6
2nd-for-cfg-6
45% 5:6=0s 2                                                                                                                                                                                               
1st-for-cfg-5
2nd-for-cfg-5
54% 6:5=0s 1                                                                                                                                                                                               
1st-for-cfg-4
2nd-for-cfg-4
63% 7:4=0s 0                                                                                                                                                                                               
1st-for-cfg-3
2nd-for-cfg-3
72% 8:3=0s 0                                                                                                                                                                                               
1st-for-cfg-2
2nd-for-cfg-2
81% 9:2=0s 0                                                                                                                                                                                               
1st-for-cfg-1
2nd-for-cfg-1
90% 10:1=0s 0                                                                                                                                                                                              
1st-for-cfg-0
2nd-for-cfg-0
```

### Update

You added:

> I should have mentioned that the config files are not necessarily sequentially named and can have any name, I just made them like this to make the example as simple as possible.

The **`< list_of_arguments`** solves this ex-post changed problem definition:

```
parallel [options] [command [arguments]] < list_of_arguments
```

Comment: Just for reference, the `--dry-run` option allows you to see the commands to be executed without actual execution.

Comment: @user3666197: That is perfect, exactly what I need. Sorry for the late update, when I wrote the MWE I did not think that the config files could be sequential. Thanks!

Comment: Always welcome @jorgehumberto - this is why **M**inimal-**C**omplete-**V**erifiable-**E**xample-of-reproducible-code philosophy was adopted as a StackOverflow standard for formulation of **S**ystem-**u**nder-**T**est reviews - solutions working this way **will help & work** - which is a common target for both the Question-asker and all the Answer-ers, isn't it? :o)

Answer (score 2):

This would be fairly simple with `find` and `xargs`.  This would run four processes in parallel, and for any given config file will complete `script1.sh` before running `script2.sh`:

```
find . -name '*.cfg' -print0 | xargs -0 -P 4 -iCFG sh -c 'script1.sh CFG && script2.sh CFG'
```

Comment: Side note: using zero terminated strings and then passing them to shell to split them on whitespaces is strange. Pass it via an argument and let shell properly expand it: `xargs -o -n1 sh -c 'script1.sh "$1" && script2.sh "$1"' --`

Comment: @larsks: Thank you, I like the 'parallel' approach better, but yours is also a good alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I did some simulation test, first I created the file like you describe.

```
printf '%s\n' cfg{1..100}.cfg > file.txt
```

Now the script to process it.

```
#!/bin/bash

file=file.txt
limit=2

array=()
while read -r cfg; do
  array+=("$cfg")
done < "$file"

for ((n=0; n<limit; n++)); do
  for ((i=n; i<${#array[@]}; i+=limit)); do
    echo script1.sh "${array[i]}" && echo script2.sh "${array[i]}" && sleep 2; echo
  done &
done

wait
```

Now if you run that script you should see what's going to happen. The echo and sleep is there just for visual aid :-), you can remove them if you decided to actually run the script. Change the value of limit to your own hearts content. The idea and technique howto solve that particular problem did not came from me. It came from this guy. https://github.com/e36freak/, give credit where it is due...

Comment: @Jetshisel: Thank you, although I prefer the 'parallel' approach, yours taught me how to make an alternate CPU counter, kudos for that! :)

Comment: Sure, use the tools that are created for the specific task at hand. Just remember there is an alternative (slower but does not require any external utility from the shell) solution just in case you found yourself not having the tool to do the task.